# Where would the majority of the Indoleacetic acid (IAA) be in the shoot and what would the effect be?

Tags: plant-anatomy

If I propose that a plant is 2D and then a light source was shone on both horizontal side of the shoot, in which direction would positive phototropism occur (or would positive phototropism occur at all?).

I am presuming that light intensity is the same and there has been no modification of the tip.